# Get Controller and Action Name whern creating Custom Authorization Policy in .NET Core 6 using IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I, am trying to configure a custom Authorization policy in .NET Core 6 with the following logic in a Handler:

1. Get Controller Name and Get Controller Action which user is trying to access
2. If Claim.Type = Controller Name and Value = Controller Action then grant access.

I, am trying to access the Controller Name and Action using IHttpContextAccessor injected into the Handler class. How can I get the controller name and action method name? I found several articles mentioning how to do so in previous versions of .NET Core. But those do not work on .NET 6. It always provides NULL value

**Current AccessHandler (Previous Versions of .NET)**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace myApp.Security
{
    public class AccessHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

        public AccessHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
        }
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AccessRequirement requirement)
        {
               
            string? controllerName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Query["controller"].ToString();

            string? actionName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Query["action"].ToString();

            if (controllerName != null && actionName != null)
            {
                if (context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == controllerName && claim.Value == actionName))
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution and the process of finding was really satisfying. Here is how you can do it in .NET 6 Core. Modify the Requirement handler as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace myApp.Security
{
    public class AccessHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AccessRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

        public AccessHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
        }
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AccessRequirement requirement)
        {
            string? controllerName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.RouteValues["controller"]?.ToString();

            string? actionName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.RouteValues["action"]?.ToString();

            if (controllerName != null && actionName != null)
            {
                if (context.User.HasClaim(claim => (claim.Type == controllerName && claim.Value == actionName)))
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```